# HP Basic anomaly in Print Using

Tags: basic, openvms, vms

As I understand it, the following statement:

```
print using "<0>#,##", 1234
```

outputs:

```
1,234
```

which makes sense; leading zeros (of which there are none) and five characters available for the five characters we want to output. Another statement which I understand is:

```
print using "<0>#####,#######", "12345678"L
```

which outputs:

```
00,012,345,678
```

again, makes sense given my understanding of the formatting characters; 14 characters available for the digits, commas, and leading zeros.

What I don't understand is how:

```
print using "<0>####,#######", "12345678"L
```

can output:

```
00,012,345,678
```

Surely that's one too many leading zeros? Surely it should be:

```
0,012,345,678
```

I can see that sometimes a leading zero is added over and above the length specified, if otherwise the output would start with a leading comma, such as in this example:

```
print using "<0>###,#######", "12345678"L
```

which produces

```
0,012,345,678
```

despite seemingly not reserving enough space. But is the previous example a bug in Basic, or am I missing something here?

Comment: BASIC compiler/RTL versions? BASIC/LIST=TT: TT:...END...^Z.   anal/image/select=ident=image sys$library:dec$basrtl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bug. It adds a bonus leading zero when <0> and the thousands separator play together.
That <0> should count for 1 position.

It reproduces for me under Basic 1.3 (OpenVMS 8.3) and 1.7-000 on OpenVMS 8.4.
I used smaller test values to avoid creating confusion/interaction with the max integer size of "Ten digits of precision for LONG integers" Basic Ref manual.

Btw.. good use of the "nnn"L. That pre-empts any (implied) conversion discussion.
I would move the comma, to the end or start of the ### sequence to avoid implying a specific position.

As a (but-uggly) workaround, you might use FORMAT$ ( val, format-string ).
It has the same problem, but the program will get a change to tweak the result.

```
$ cre tmp.bas
 1      OPTION TYPE = EXPLICIT, SIZE = INTEGER LONG, CONSTANT TYPE = INTEGER
        print using "<0>###,", 1234
        print using "<0>###,", 123
        print using "<0>###,", 12
        print using "<0>###", 1234
        print using "<0>###", 123
        print using "<0>###", 12
 Exit
$ bas tmp
$ link tmp
$ run tmp
1,234
00,123
00,012
1234
0123
0012
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming it as a bug!   I've also noticed occasions when it fails to add a leading zero. For example "<0>##########,",1234 produces "000,001,234", (which is the same output you get if you add another # to the format string.).